# php - do something on user sharing of a link on facebook

Tags: php, facebook

Is there a way to run php code after user shares a link on facebook from my site? 
I tried this code but after link sharing I'm not redirected to

```
<div id="shareBtn">Share</div>
<script>
document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    redirect_uri: 'https://domain.ext/landing.php',
    display: 'popup',
    href: 'https://domain.ext/link',
  }, function(response){});
}
</script>
```

I probably can't know if post privacy will be private or if post will be deleted after sharing, but I must be sure that users share effectively the link before being redirected to 
how can I do? 
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to know if the user shared it?

Comment: because I give them virtual "points" on my site if they share

Comment: That is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy. I recommend you read it

Comment: Ok I'll do it , and there's nothing similar that can I do about this

Comment: If you read the policy you would see it say that you can not reward the user in any way for sharing